# How is the acceleration proportional to the net force over the mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration

The acceleration is inversely proportional to the mass **when the force is constant**.

Also, the acceleration is proportional to the force **when the mass is constant**.

So, how can the acceleration be proportional to the net force over the mass without considering the mass or the force to be constant?

Comment: Hint: Newton's 2nd law and the definition of momentum.

Comment: The mass is constant in nonrelativistic dynamics.

Comment: Newton's second law doesn't require the force to be constant. The force and thus acceleration need not be constant.  If the force varies in time, then the acceleration will vary in time. As far as mass is concerned,  Newton's second law normally assumes the mass is constant (which is the case for non-relativistic velocities).

Comment: The mass may also change, dp/dt = F.

Answer (score 4):

Saying that $X$ is proportional to $A/B$ does not imply that either $A$ or $B$ is constant.  Saying that $X$ is proportional to $A/B$ means that

- (1) $X$ depends on two things, $A$ and $B$,
- (2) if $A$ is replaced by $sA$, then $X$ is replaced by $sX$,
- (3) if $B$ is replaced by $rB$, then $X$ is replaced by $X/r$.

Altogether, if $A$ is replaced by $sA$ and $B$ is replaced by $rB$, then $X$ is replaced by $sX/r$.